# How to get installed apps which have SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission enabled?

Tags: android, android-permissions

I want to find all apps with **enabled** SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission installed on the device.

First of all I found all apps with SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission and I verified that the list is correct: on my phone I went to Settings -> Special app access -> Display over other apps.
Then I disabled "Allow display over other apps" option for **all** apps under "Display over other apps" menu.
Next, I started my app again and I found out that list of apps with SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission still the same.

I decided to *check* if permission is granted or not. I used the following:

> PackageManager.checkPermission(SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW, package name) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED

But this check returned `true` for all packages with SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permisson! Moreover, this check returns `true` even if package doesn't have SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission at all.

My code is below:

```
public ArrayList<String> getAppsWhichHaveOverlaySettingEnabled() {
    ArrayList<String> apps = new ArrayList<>();

    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    List<PackageInfo> installedPackages = pm.getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS | PackageManager.GET_PROVIDERS);

    for (PackageInfo packageInfo : installedPackages) {
        String[] requestedPermissions = packageInfo.requestedPermissions;

        if (requestedPermissions != null) {
            for (String requestedPermission : requestedPermissions) {
                if (requestedPermission.equals(SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW)) {
                    if (pm.checkPermission(SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW, packageInfo.packageName) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        String name = pm.getApplicationLabel(packageInfo.applicationInfo).toString();
                        apps.add(name + " (" + packageInfo.packageName + ")");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return apps;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Or it is not possible to get such information at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked my method and another app with similar method on several Android devices and looks like it is not possible to get list of apps with **currently enabled** SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission.

If SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission was granted to app once then check methods will return **true** no matter whether this permission currently enabled or not.

Still, the more accurate way to check such a permission is:

```
public ArrayList<String> getAppsWhichHaveOverlaySettingEnabled() {
    ArrayList<String> apps = new ArrayList<>();

    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    List<PackageInfo> installedPackages = pm.getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);

    for (PackageInfo packageInfo : installedPackages) {
        String[] requestedPermissions = packageInfo.requestedPermissions;

        if (requestedPermissions != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < requestedPermissions.length; i++) {
                String requestedPermission = requestedPermissions[i];
                if (requestedPermission.equals(SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW)) {
                    if ((packageInfo.requestedPermissionsFlags[i] & REQUESTED_PERMISSION_GRANTED) == REQUESTED_PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        String name = pm.getApplicationLabel(packageInfo.applicationInfo).toString();
                        apps.add(name + " (" + packageInfo.packageName + ")");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return apps;
}
```

Read more [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html#requestedPermissionsFlags).

Comment: I think what you did here is about the declaration existence of each permission. Not about whether they are granted or not. For that, the code I've created always returns "false": issuetracker.google.com/issues/235698912#comment2 . Is there still no way to check this even today? Only thing I've found is via IPC: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/PermissionChecker#checkSelfPermission(android.content.Context,java.lang.String)